# Passing value to store getters Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to pass ID as parameter to store getter, but when i console that id I get undefined.
Can someone help me with this:

Here is my code:

This is how i call getter:

```
this.$store.getters['users/list']('users', '123')
```

This is getter function:

```
getters: {
    list: (state, getters, rootState, rootGetters, userId) => (key) => {
      console.log(userId)
    }
  }
```

Comment: to your last deleted question, you could take `array = Object.assign([], object)` for getting an array of an objects with an object with array like keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close:

```
new Vuex.Store({
  getters: {
    someMethod: (state) => (userid) => {
        console.log(userid);
      }
    };       
  }
})
```